# RX: testing Sample\Interval\Switch pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have some RX code to test for inactivity on an event stream, activity on the stream resets an interval which is the inactivity trigger.

```
public interface IReportActivity
{
    event EventHandler Activity;
}

public interface IInactivityMonitor
{
    IObservable<Unit> ObserveInactivity(TimeSpan inactivityTimeout);
}

public class InactivityMonitor : IInactivityMonitor
{
    private readonly ISchedulerProvider _schedulerProvider;
    private readonly IReportActivity _activitySource;
    private IObservable<Unit> _inactivityObservable;

    public InactivityMonitor(IRaiseActivity activitySource, ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider)
    {
        _activitySource = activitySource;
        _schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> ObserveInactivity(TimeSpan inactivityTimeout)
    {
        return GetInactivityObservable()
            .Select(_ => Observable.Interval(inactivityTimeout, _schedulerProvider.NewThread)
                    .Timestamp()
                    .Select(__ => Unit.Default))
            .Switch();
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> GetInactivityObservable()
    {
        return _inactivityObservable = _inactivityObservable ??
            Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<EventArgs>, EventArgs>(
                h => _activitySource.Activity += h,
                h => _activitySource.Activity -= h)
                .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _schedulerProvider.NewThread)
                .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                .Publish()
                .RefCount();
    }
}
```

The code works as required (although I think recreating the Interval every second is over kill - ObserveInactivity should Sample just before the timeout and reset based on the timestamp of the last activity)

The real issue I have is trying to test this code.

```
[TestFixture]
public class InactivityMonitorTests
{
    private TestSchedulers _testSchedulers;
    private InactivityMonitor _sut;
    private AutoMock _moqqer;

    protected override void Setup()
    {
        base.Setup();

        _moqqer = new AutoMock()
        _testSchedulers = new TestSchedulers();
        _moqqer.Use<ISchedulerProvider>(_testSchedulers);
        _sut = Moqqer.CreateInstance<InactivityMonitor>();
    }

    // this test passes
    [Test]
    public void GetInactivityObservable_ActivityDetected_ReportsActivity()
    {
        var activityObserved = false;

        _sut.GetInactivityObservable()
           .Subscribe(x => activityObserved = true);

        RaiseActivityEvent();

        _testSchedulers.NewThread.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11).Ticks);

        activityObserved.Should().BeTrue();
    }

    private void RaiseActivityEvent()
    {
        _moqqer.GetMock<IReportActivty>()
          .Raise(m => m.Activity += null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // this test fails, The interval never appears to get set up via the tests.
    [Test]
    public void ObserveActivity_InactivtyTimeoutExceeded_NotificationReceived()
    {
       var inactivityObserved = false;

        _sut.ObserveInactivity(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
           .Subscribe(x => inactivityObserved = true);

       _testSchedulers.NewThread.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11).Ticks);

       inactivityObserved.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}

public interface ISchedulerProvider
{
    IScheduler CurrentThread { get; }
    IScheduler Dispatcher { get; }
    IScheduler Immediate { get; }
    IScheduler NewThread { get; }
    IScheduler ThreadPool { get; }

    IScheduler TaskPool { get; } 
}

public sealed class TestSchedulers : ISchedulerProvider
{
    private readonly TestScheduler _currentThread = new TestScheduler();
    private readonly TestScheduler _dispatcher = new TestScheduler();
    private readonly TestScheduler _immediate = new TestScheduler();
    private readonly TestScheduler _newThread = new TestScheduler();
    private readonly TestScheduler _threadPool = new TestScheduler();
    private readonly TestScheduler _taskPool = new TestScheduler();
    #region Explicit implementation of ISchedulerService
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.CurrentThread { get { return _currentThread; } }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.Dispatcher { get { return _dispatcher; } }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.Immediate { get { return _immediate; } }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.NewThread { get { return _newThread; } }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.ThreadPool { get { return _threadPool; } }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.TaskPool { get { return _taskPool; } }

    #endregion
    public TestScheduler CurrentThread { get { return _currentThread; } }
    public TestScheduler Dispatcher { get { return _dispatcher; } }
    public TestScheduler Immediate { get { return _immediate; } }
    public TestScheduler NewThread { get { return _newThread; } }
    public TestScheduler ThreadPool { get { return _threadPool; } }
    public TestScheduler TaskPool { get { return _taskPool; } }
}
```

I've tried various ways to start the scheduler, before subscribing and after, trying to subscribe on another scheduler and starting that before subscribe but no success.

EDIT: Debugging shows that the interval is never getting created in ObserveInactivity method.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to guess your `ISchedulerProvider` and `TestSchedulers` is from http://introtorx.com?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that in the original post.

Comment: have posted the code for the scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-organise your inactivity query to so that instead of being triggered from `_activitySource.Activity` and then adding time to that, you instead expect failure/silence in XXX period and raise a notifcation for that. You then upgrade that query to cancel/restart if there was any activity.

i.e. instead of

```
public IObservable<Unit> GetInactivityObservable()
{
    return _inactivityObservable = _inactivityObservable ??
        Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<EventArgs>, EventArgs>(
            h => _activitySource.Activity += h,
            h => _activitySource.Activity -= h)
            .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _schedulerProvider.NewThread)
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
}
```

change that around to

```
public IObservable<Unit> GetInactivityObservable()
{
    return _inactivityObservable = _inactivityObservable ??
        Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<EventArgs>, EventArgs>(
            h => _activitySource.Activity += h,
            h => _activitySource.Activity -= h)
            .Select(_=>Unit.Default)
            .StartWith(Unit.Default)
            .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _schedulerProvider.NewThread)
            .Select(a=>Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _schedulerProvider.NewThread).Select(_=>Unit.Default))
            .Switch()
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
}
```

And then, as Rx is already lazily evaluated, I would make this method static and non side-effecting and call it in your constructor, or just inline it.

```
public class InactivityMonitor : IInactivityMonitor
{
    private readonly ISchedulerProvider _schedulerProvider;
    private readonly IObservable<Unit> _inactivityObservable;
    private static readonly TimeSpan SilencePeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

public InactivityMonitor(IRaiseActivity activitySource, ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider)
{
    _schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    _inactivityObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<EventArgs>, EventArgs>(
            h => _activitySource.Activity += h,
            h => _activitySource.Activity -= h)
            .StartWith(null)
            .Select(a=>Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _schedulerProvider.NewThread))
            .Switch()
            .Select(_=>Unit.Default)
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
}

//...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So, having a chance to get back to this problem I saw the error in my ways.

The Observable.Interval is never being started as no activity has been reported (by the misnamed inactivity observable). Running the app there is most likely at least 1 event raised. To fix this I added `.StartWith(Unit.Default)` as below, this allows the timeout to be started immediately for each observer which was obviously a potential bug in the original implementation.

```
public IObservable<Unit> ObserveInactivity(TimeSpan inactivityTimeout)
{
    return GetInactivityObservable()
        .StartWith(Unit.Default)  // <--
        .Select(_ => Observable.Interval(inactivityTimeout, _schedulerProvider.NewThread)
                .Timestamp()
                .Select(__ => Unit.Default))
        .Switch();
}
```